# How to read AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed from asp code

Tags: iis, asp-classic

In order to change the maximum upload size in IIS, the user can adjust in the IIS metabase the AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed value as explained in different sites.

My question is:

Is it possible to read the current maximum allowed size for uploads from classic Asp code?

Explanation:
I'm adjusting some upload code, and one feature now is to notify the client side of the maximum upload size so that files sent with Flash or FormData can be validated and not even try to send them if they are too large and the upload would fail. So I can either hope that when the users configure it, correctly write in the configuration file the maximum allowed by their server; but it would be much better if I can get the real value from IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx) to do that. For instance, using VBScript:

```
Dim provider, setting, maxUploadSize
Set provider = GetObject("winmgmts:/root/MicrosoftIISv2")
Set setting = provider.Get("IIsWebVirtualDirSetting='W3SVC/1/ROOT'")
maxUploadSize = setting.AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know anything about that, but it seems that it won't work. According to this http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4b976f46-3751-4f6b-ab68-5e19fa73a7b1.mspx?mfr=true the anonymous access must be disabled and I must login with an account with enough permissions to modify the metabase (that makes sense). In fact, I've tried and all I get is a unknown exception in the GetObject

Comment: @Alfonso, too bad, I was hoping read access would be allowed from ASP. Maybe you can host that code in a COM+ component running under an admin account and call that component from ASP?

Comment: Creating a component and using an admin account is out of scope for this project. It's meant to be used by "anyone", so I can't expect them being able to install components or getting priviledged accounts. I'll wait a little and if no one else provides another option I'll accept your answer as "it's only possible if you have priviledges", not what I wanted, but at least I won't keep on searching for it.